# Update UIProgressView from background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiprogressview

I have a tab bar application with three tabs. In my second tab view i have a `UIProgressView`. I have a NSTimer in my `viewDidLoad` method which calls a method which updates the progressView

```
progressTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

All is fine so far.

I want to know how do i run the timer in the background throughout the lifecycle of the app, so that `progressView` is updated no matter which view the user is in. It will be great if you can show me with a code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to update UI elements from background threads. Also, it's not advisable to modify UI elements of a view when the user is not in that view. You are using precious system resources.

Better way is to update the ProgressBar as soon as that view becomes active...

**UPDATE**: You can see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869217/iphone-ios-running-in-separate-thread) to know how to run a task in background thread. You could set up your `NSTimer` to start in the selector you specify there. But again, this kind of stuff could lead to some weird bugs. Better to avoid..

Comment: Thanks. But I am just trying to simulate a concept here. This will be just for a demo and will not submit the app to appstore.

Comment: As an addition to this answer: setup your timer in `viewWillAppear` and stop/release it in `viewWillDisappear` methods of your viewController. `NSTimer` retains its delegate and if you don't do that, your viewController can never be released.

Comment: what is the concept you trying to simulate?

Comment: @srikar i am trying to show the progress of a system. ahhhh..ok..Now i get it. I need not update the progressView from other view. I can do that in the `viewWillAppear` method also. But how do i keep running the timer in the background so that the `count` will keep on increasing over time

Comment: @srikar : can you please help me ?

Comment: @Neelesh, you need to see my update in the answer. What you essentially need to do is to start a background thread, start your NSTimer there & keep the thread & timer running.This should get what you want...

Comment: I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421817/iphone-sdkcall-a-function-in-the-background and i guess it works now. thanks

Comment: Cool! if any answer actually helped you solve your problem, go the extra step & upvote this answer & mark it as selected answer. It'll help the community...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a property in the ProgressViewController (or even in the app delegate), say a `float` that tracks the progress. When you need to update the progress, another ViewController can change the value of the property.

Once the view becomes visible, update the UI (`UIProgressView`) from `viewWillAppear:`.

Answer (score 0):

u can add the method in background this way

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// Add code here to do background processing
// increment the progress here and keep the property of that count in appdelegate 
//
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Add code here to update the UI/send notifications based on the
    // results of the background processing
});
```

});

in diffent view's viewWillAppear u can set this way:
[loadingProgressView setProgress: appDelegate.count];